# How is D.Knuth MMIX instruction MXOR useful for finite field multiplication?

Tags: galois-theory, integer-programming

Knuths TAOCP, Fascicle 1, exercise 37 (page 26) - http://mmix.cs.hm.edu/doc/fasc1.pdf:

Explain how to use MXOR for arithmetic in a field of 256 elements; each element of the field should be **represented by a suitable octabyte**.

I'm not more wiser from exercise answer on page 96. :-(

I have for example 2 elements in $GF(2^8)$: `0xCA` and `0x53`, irreducible polynomial `0x11B`: $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$. How EXACTLY these two bytes can be multiplied by MXOR and correct result (`0x01` - they are inverse of each other) can be achieved?

Comment: D'oh, my vol. 1 doesn't describe MIX before section 1.3 on page 120 ... and there's no `MXOR` in it

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Note that Fascicle 1 is presumably not for vol. I, but rather an initial portion of [vol. IV for TAOCP](http://www.amazon.com/The-Computer-Programming-Volume-Fascicle/dp/0321580508), "Bitwise Tricks & Techniques...".

Comment: I added URL for Fascicle 1

Answer (score 1):

One-sentence summary: the idea is to think of GF(256) as an 8-dimensional vector space over GF(2), and to represent an element $t$ of GF(256) by the 8x8 matrix describing the linear transformation on this vector space "multiplication by $t$. Details follow:

With your chosen irreducible poly, we have $x^8=x^4+x^3+x+1$. Now, *temporarily* represent an element of the field by an 8-element column vector whose entries are the coeffs of $1,x,\dots,x^7$. (This is *not* the representation Knuth is looking for. It's part of the explanation.) Multiplication by $x$ corresponds to multiplying this vector on the left by some matrix; call it $A$. This will send $1$ to $x$, ..., $x^6$ to $x^7$ ... and $x^7$ to $1+x+x^3+x^4$. So $A$ has to be

$$\left(\matrix{0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1 \\ 1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0}\right)$$

which looking at Knuth's answer is not quite the same convention as he's using (he's thinking of row rather than column vectors) but it doesn't matter.

OK. Now, **the representation of any element of the field is going to be what we get by replacing $x$ with $A$ everywhere**. (And then turning the resulting matrix into an "octabyte" in standard MMIX fashion.) So, e.g., if I'm understanding you correctly then `0xCA` means $x+x^3+x^6+x^7$ which means we need $A+A^3+A^6+A^7$, and `0x53` means $1+x+x^4+x^6$ which means we need $1+A+A^4+A^6$ where of course $1$ here means the identity matrix.

These work out to be

$$\left(\matrix{0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&0&1&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1 \\ 1&0&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\ 1&1&0&0&0&0&0&1}\right)
\hbox{and}
\left(\matrix{1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0 \\ 1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1 \\ 0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1 \\ 0&0&0&1&0&1&0&1 \\ 1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\ 1&0&1&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&1&0&1&0&0}\right)$$

if I haven't mistranscribed them; and you can check that their product mod 2 (i.e., the result of `MXOR`) is the identity matrix, as it should be. (I have done so, so if it doesn't work out then I probably did mistranscribe.)

In some sense this is a very inefficient way to represent elements of GF(256) -- we are using 64 bits when 8 bits really should suffice. But it plays well with the capabilities of MMIX: the field operations are just ordinary addition and `MXOR`.